# how i can view image dynamicly either png or jpg ..etc

Tags: php, html

I need to view images ,but my code doesn't know if the image png or jpg 
Please I need you help

```
<?php
    // Get all members
    $members = "";
    $results = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT id,fullname FROM trainees");
    if(!empty($results)) {
     foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
      $members.= '
       <li>
        <img src="images/user-images/'.$row["id"].'.*'.'" alt="User Image">
         <a class="users-list-name" href="#">'.$row["fullname"].'</a>
         <span class="users-list-date">'.$row["sub_from"].'</span>
         </li>';
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: why do you need to know the extension of the image?

Comment: If you don't know what object you want to reference, then you cannot reference it. But I wonder what kind of architecture that is where you don't know that... If this is only about some file name (which I suspect), then why should you be interested in something old fashioned like a "file name extension"? It is worthless. Store the files without.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the code. If your users have an image stored (a user-image) - the name of that file should be stored in the database with the rest of the information. Not the image-file itself, just the name of the file you need to fetch for that specific user.

If that's not an option, and you always know that it's EITHER jpg or png, then you could do a check for that, using file_exists() - something like this:

```
<img src="images/user-images/'.$row['id'].'.(file_exists($row['id'].'.png' ? '.png' : '.jpg').'" alt="User Image">
```

This assumes quite a few things - first, that the filename is just user id with the extension after, second, that the file is always either a .png or a .jpg-file, and third, that the file always exist (since the second clause in that ternary operator will show if the .png is not present, regardless of whether or not the file is there at all).

Answer (score 0):

Much appreciated for your help but this code helped me

```
<?php
// Get all members
$members = "";
$results = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT id,fullname,sub_from FROM trainees LIMIT 8");
if(!empty($results)) {
  foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
if (file_exists('images/user-images/'.$row["id"].'.jpg')) {
  $img = '<img src="images/user-images/'.$row["id"].'.jpg'.'" alt="User Image">';
} else if (file_exists('images/user-images/'.$row["id"].'.jpg')) {
  $img = '<img src="images/user-images/'.$row["id"].'.png'.'" alt="User Image">';
}else
 $img = '<img src="images/user-images/avatar.png" alt="User Image">';

    $members.= '
    <li>'.$img.'
     <a class="users-list-name" href="#">'.$row["fullname"].'</a>
     <span class="users-list-date">'.$row["sub_from"].'</span>
    </li>';
  }
}
?>
```